# Trouble using find function in C++

Tags: c++, list, vector, linked-list, find

I am trying to find the difference in my code when I use std::find.

For my test code. I made a Vector called Test

```
std::vector<const char*> Test;
```

To test the find function, I filled the Test vector with dummy data by using push_back function

```
Test.push_back("F_S");
Test.push_back("FC");
Test.push_back("ID");
Test.push_back("CD");
Test.push_back("CT");
Test.push_back("DS");
Test.push_back("CR");
Test.push_back("5K_2");
Test.push_back("10K_5");
Test.push_back("10K_1");
Test.push_back("10K_2");
Test.push_back("10K_3");
Test.push_back("10K_4");
Test.push_back("10K_5");
```

What I want to do with the find function is to go through the Test and see if there are any repeated data. The first time a encounter the data, I will save it to a vector called Unique_Data.

```
std::vector<const char*> Unique_Data;
```

So for the 14 data points above, only 13 will be saved because 10K_5 repeated.

The Code I am using looks like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < Test.size(); i++) 
    {
        if( Unique_Data.empty())
        {
            Unique_Data.push_back(Test[i]);
        }
        else if (std::find(Unique_Data.begin(), Unique_Data.end(), Test[i]) != Unique_Data.end())
        {
            // Move on to next index
        }
        else
        {
            Unique_Data.push_back(Test[i]);
        }
    }
```

The problem I am having is when I am using the dummy data. I am getting a correct answer for Unique_Data.

However, if I save the actual data into the Test vector which are saved in linked list. I get that they are all unique.

The code looks like this

```
p_curr = List.p_root;
    while(p_curr != NULL)
    {
            // id starts from 0
        if(atoi(p_curr->id) == 14) break;
        Test.push_back(p_curr->Descriptor);

        p_curr = p_curr->p_next;
    }
```

I tested with the same 14 data. They are all const char* types. However, when I used the linked list data. The find function thinks all the data is unique.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: You would do your self a favor by using `std::string` instead of `const char*`. Since the `const char*` are compared by pointer value, not to the text they might contain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using C-style strings is a bit tricky, they are just a pointer, and pointers are compared by identity. Two C strings with the same sequence of characters, but different addresses will compare different.

```
const char first[] = "Hi";
const char second[] = "Hi";
assert(first == second);     // will fail!
```

There are two solutions to this problem. The simple one is using `std::string` in your container, as `std::string` will provide value comparisons. The alternative is to pass a comparison functor to `std::find` as a last argument. But this will still leave the problem of managing the lifetime of the `const char*`-s stored in the vector.

Comment: That assert may fail, but compiler may optimize and store the same string literals on the same address. I be this happened to the OP and that's why his test works.

Comment: That assert actually should not fail (although it _could_ depending on the compiler), and in fact that is precisely the problem that the OP was having!

Comment: @user2711915: That assert **must** fail, since I am not constructing two *pointers* to the same literal string, but two *arrays*. That is, `&first != &second`, and when they decay to `const char*`, `first != second`. Try it in your compiler of choice.

Comment: I was not aware that the compiler would not perform the same optimisation it does on `const char *` for `const char []`, even though it could for exactly the same reasons as in the former case. Anyway this misses the point that the OP wasn't just having the problem that when comparing `char *`s identical cstrings did not match, he was having the problem that in his test data identical cstrings did match, as the compiler was optimising the storage of the data for his literals.

Comment: @user2711915: No, it cannot do that optimization. When you have a literal it is fine, you create as many pointers as you want, each pointer will be *unique* but the pointed memory can be the same. In this case the variable is the array itself.

Comment: @user2711915: The compiler could optimize that call away if you never compared the addresses, but since you compare them merging them would break the *as-if* rule

Comment: Interesting that they could easily be the same until you check if they are the same. It is also interesting that doing so in the case of `char *` does not violate the as-if rule, given that in the case of the OP the compiler changes (at compile time) the result of comparing the memory addresses of `const char *`s depending on the contents of the `const char *`s. While it is not quite the same as the arrays issue, and obviously the default behaviour will never be changed, the fluidity between `const char *` used with literals changing addresses does lead to surprises, but in 1973 was worth it.

Comment: @user2711915: The difference is that when you type: `const char* p = "Hi";` there is no contract or obligation as of where `"Hi"` will be stored. Nothing in the standard mandates that the literal itself is shared or not. There is an obligation that `p` is different from `q` in `const char* q = "Hi";` or `const char* q = p;`, but no requirements on the value that gets assigned. That is why it does not break the *as-if*. Your program cannot depend on some behavior, so any option is as good as any other one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pointers problem. You're not storing strings in your array, you're storing the memory address of the data in the string.

This strange behaviour is probably because in your example case you have literal strings that cannot be changed, so the compiler is optimising the storage, and when two strings are the same then it stores the same address for all strings that have the same text.

In your real data example, you have a bunch of strings that hold the same data, but each of these strings lives at a different memory address, so the find function is saying that all strings have a different address.

In summary, your find function is looking at the memory address of the string, not the data (text) in the string. If you use std::strings then this problem will disappear.

I would highly recommend using strings, as performance is going to be more than good enough and they eliminate a vast number of problems.

Answer (score 0):

As David Rodriguez mentions in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20406435/241631), you're only comparing pointers, and not the contents of the strings themselves. Your solution will work as is if you were storing `std::string`s instead of `char const *`. With the latter, you need to resort to `std::find_if` and a predicate that calls `strcmp` to determine whether the strings are identical.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    std::vector<const char*> Test;
    Test.push_back("F_S");
    Test.push_back("FC");
    Test.push_back("ID");
    Test.push_back("CD");
    Test.push_back("CT");
    Test.push_back("DS");
    Test.push_back("CR");
    Test.push_back("5K_2");
    Test.push_back("10K_5");
    Test.push_back("10K_1");
    Test.push_back("10K_2");
    Test.push_back("10K_3");
    Test.push_back("10K_4");
    Test.push_back("10K_5");

    std::vector<const char*> Unique_Data;

    for(auto const& s1 : Test) {
        if(std::find_i(Unique_Data.cbegin(), Unique_Data.cend(), 
            [&](const char *s2) { return std::strcmp(s1, s2) == 0; })
            == Unique_Data.cend()) {
            Unique_Data.push_back(s1);
        }
    }

    for(auto const& s : Unique_Data) {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    }
}
```

Here's a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51bf0de05b4faf00)